# I cannot hear the music of an app which is developed by me when the Windows 8 phone is in sleep mode

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

The music is automatically stopped when the phone is in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

For background audio [BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) should be used. See a tutorial at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: will you please tell me how to do it using phonegap?

Comment: Actually you need to write a phonegap plugin. Than is not difficult. See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html Or you can try to google for an existing one.